# Bootstrapped hclust with real data

Tags: r, bootstrapping, hclust

I have a dataset with multiple observations for each category:

```
country PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4 PC5
BD  0.0960408090569664  0.373740208940467   -0.369920989335273  -1.02993010449105   -0.481901935725247
BD  -0.538617581045194  0.537010643603669   0.447050616992454   -1.3888975041278    -0.759524281163431
PK  -0.452943925236246  0.507244835779749   0.64679762176707    -1.38054973938184   -0.278384245105666
PK  -1.01487954986928   0.737191371806965   -0.202656866687033  -1.22663700666619   0.186305912881529
UK  -0.377594639422628  0.817593863033578   0.3739216019342 -1.73856626173224   1.12404906217336
UK  -0.636564327570674  0.714647668634421   1.00488527275837    -1.4344227886331    0.637219423443802
US  -0.775649983771687  0.0900448150403809  0.243317360780493   -1.72498526814162   -0.618714136277983
US  -0.372815509141658  0.419096654055852   0.904247466040119   -0.573219421959129  -0.0154666267035251
```

I want to run hierarchical cluster analysis on it in R, such that there are only 4 nodes (corresponding to 4 levels of `country`). The only way I can think of is to take mean values of the columns (`PC1`, `PC2`...) based on `country` and then run `hclust` in R. Since I have multiple observations for each categorical variable (there are at least 200 for each level), I want to run a bootstrap version of hierarchical cluster analysis on thousands of sub-samples (by randomly selecting one observation for each categorical variable) and running `hclust`, and then get a final result. I have come across the following ways of bootstrap clustering. [pvclust](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pvclust/index.html) appears to be useful for the summarised version of this data. [ClusterBootstrap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ClusterBootstrap/index.html) and [Bclust](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/shipunov/html/Bclust.html) also do not look useful for my scenario. Any ideas how can I run bootstrap using sub-samples of actual observations instead of using the summarized version with /without replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap cluster analysis is possible as follows:

```
library(future)
plan(multisession)
library(shipunov)
library(dplyr)
data = data.frame(country = c(rep("PK", 10), rep("UK", 10), rep("US", 10), rep("BD", 10), rep("IN", 10)),
                  "PC1" = runif(n = 50, min = -2, max = 3),
                  "PC2" = runif(n = 50, min = -2.5, max = 4),
                  "PC3" = runif(n = 50, min = -4, max = 2))
#original that will be used for comparison
d1 = data |> 
  dplyr::group_by(country) |> 
  dplyr::summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) |> 
  tibble::column_to_rownames(var="country") |> 
  data.frame()
dist_mat <- dist(d1, method = 'euclidean')
list_of_hc <- furrr::future_map(1:20000, function(i) {
  print(i)
  ##create a dataframe with replacement using original df and summarize it
  d = data |> group_by(country) |> slice_sample(prop = 1, replace=TRUE) |>
    ungroup() |> 
    dplyr::group_by(country) |> 
    dplyr::summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) |> 
    tibble::column_to_rownames(var="country")
  ##run hclust on the data
  dist_mat = dist(d, method = 'euclidean')
  hc =  hclust(dist_mat)
  ##save the hclust result to a list
  hc}, .progress = TRUE)
#first element of the list is based on original df
list_of_hc[[1]] <- hclust(dist_mat)
#use Bclust to calculate similarity b/w the original (first element) and subsequent bootstrapped hclust
(bb3 <- Bclust(hclist=list_of_hc, relative = TRUE))
plot(bb3)
```

Result:
[image: result of Bclust as a plot]